# ¿Cual es la forma correcta de borrar un objeto creado de forma dentro de un arreglo estatico?

Tags: c++, punteros

Solo tengo la curiosidad de saber si la forma que estoy eliminando objetos alojados en la memoria de forma dinámica es correcta. Ya que quiero evitar el dejar la memoria llena al momento de estar probando todo lo que necesito

Tengo mi clase de ejemplo

```cpp
class Cancion{
private:
    string nombre;
public:
    Cancion();
    Cancion(const Cancion&);

    virtual ~Cancion();

    void setNombre(const string &);

    string getNombre() const;
};
```

Y tengo otra clase que simula una lista que es un arreglo estático pero que contiene apuntadores de mi clase de ejemplo, lo hago de esta forma ya que es un requisito para esto:

```cpp
template<class T, int TAM = 50>
class Lista{
private:
    T* datos[TAM];
    int ultimo;
public:
    Lista();

    virtual ~Lista();

    void insertar(const int &, const T &);

    void borrar(const int &);
};
```

Así es como lo estoy "insertando" si se puede decir de esta forma

```cpp
template<class T, int MAXSIZE>
inline void List<T, MAXSIZE>::insertData(const int &p, const T &e)
{
    int i(last);
    while (i > p)
    {
        //el siguiente puntero tiene lo que
        //hay en el indice anterior
        data[i + 1] = data[i];
        i--;
    }
    //inserccion despues del punto de interes
    data[p + 1] = new T(e);
    last++;
}
```

Esta es la forma que lo estoy borrando

```cpp
template<class T, int MAXSIZE>
inline void List<T, MAXSIZE>::deleteData(const int &p)
{
    int i(p);
    while (i < last)
    {
        data[i] = data[i + 1];
        i++;
    }
    -----------------------------------
    delete data[last]; -------> //apartir de aquí ¿esta bien?
    data[last] = nullptr;
    ----------------------------------

    last--;
}
```

Debido a que me llego la duda de que si no estoy borrando el puntero y no la dirección a la que apunta, no tiene lógica pero estoy aprendiendo a usarlos.

Comment: ¿`List` y `Lista` son la misma clase?

Answer (score 2):

El operador `delete` **recibe una dirección de memoria** y borra (invoca el destructor) de lo que hay apuntado en dicha dirección.

Es decir, no borras el puntero; el puntero sigue existiendo pero apuntando a un objeto cuya vida ha finalizado. Lo puedes comprobar mostrando el puntero antes y después del borrado y observando que contiene la misma dirección:

```
std::cout << data[last] << '\n';
delete data[last];
std::cout << data[last] << '\n';
```